# Xubuntu 17.10: disable screen locking when connected to a specific WiFi network

Tags: networking, scripts, xubuntu, cron, light-locker

I'm running Xubuntu 17.10 and I would like to remove screen
locking when I'm connected to my home wifi.

My current plan is something like:

1. Use a `/etc/interfaces/if.up/` script to check when I'm connected
    to my wifi (using `iwconfig` to get the SSID)
2. To do this, I've read that the wifi interface must be in
    interfaces. It is currently not. But if I add it there, will it
    still connect to networks automatically as it does out of the
    box?
3. Then, I'm not sure how to disable light-locker (and only
    temporarily). Can light-locker be commanded from the CLI?
4. Then, have a `if.down` / `if.up` script that does turns on
    light-locker whenever I disconnect from the wifi or connect to
    some other network.

An alternative method would be to just have a cron script that runs
every 1 min and toggles light-locker as a function of the connection.

So to summarize my questions:

1. How to enable/disable light-locker programmatically from within
   a script that is run at `if.down` / `if.up` or in `cron`?
2. Can I add an interface to /etc/interfaces file so that `if.up` /
   `if.down` scripts can run, and still manage the interface automatically
   using as usual?

Edit: after some research, it seems i should rather use the NetworkManager dispatcher instead of `if.up`/`if.down` scripts. This would invalidate question 1.

Comment: If Eve walks past your house, her phone will register your router's SSID+mac, letting her set up a router at the café with the same name as the one you're checking against (but no encryption). I wouldn't use simply SSID/mac here, though I guess it might be fairly safe if you also try to ssh into the router and check that the host key didn't change (or something equivalent)